# Conditions under which $BA = I_{n}$, where $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ . I want to to know what conditions can I apply  on the matrix $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ such that product  $BA = I_{n}$ or matrix $B$ is the left inverse of the matrix $A$.

Please help me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just so you know the standard notation for matrices is $M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{C})$. In this case one necessary condition is that $n\leq m$, it's not really a condition on B. For B you want that $B|_{Im(A)}=A^{-1}$, beyond that what kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: @OwenSizemore Thanks for the comment. We can't talk about $A^{-1}$ here since matrix $A$ is rectangular. All I want to know can I impose certain conditions on $B$ such that $BA$ is identity matrix always?

Comment: What I meant is that if you think of $A$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to Im(A) then, if ker(A)=$\{0\}$, we can find an inverse. Also what do you mean by always? Do you mean for all A? this is not possible. For example, as I implied above, if ker(A)$\neq \{0\}$ then no B will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, as @OwenSizemore correctly suggested, if $n\leq m$ and A is a full rank matrix, then we can think of some Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse type of solution.

If not, then I'm not sure if this is even possible. Given a vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathbf{Ax=v}$ we can't really get $\mathbf{x}$ since given a solution $\mathbf{x_0}$ to this equation, $\mathbf{x_0+n}$ is also a solution ($\mathbf{n}$ is any vector in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$), right?